# Render a component only when a condition is fulfilled, it shows 0 otherwise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, filter, jsx

I want a component to be shown only when a condition is true, otherwise don't show anything. But in this case it shows a zero `0` when the conditions is not met.

This is the code:

```
  const documents = [
    { types: [{}], value: 'good' },
    { types: [], value: 'bad' },
    { types: [{}, {}, {}], value: 'good' },
    { types: [{}], value: 'bad' }
  ];
  const toCheck = 'good';
  return (
    documents.filter((a) => a.types.length && a.value === toCheck).length && (
      <div>render this component</div>
    )
  );
```

When the result of filter is greater than zero the component is rendered, when the result is 0 it shows a 0. I want show nothing when the condition is not true.

How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

> I want show nothing when the condition is not true.

Your code currently returns `0` when the condition is false. To render nothing, you have to return `null` or `false`:

```
return (
    documents.filter((a) => a.types.length && a.value === toCheck).length
        ? <div>render this component</div>
        : null
);
```

As Patrick Roberts points out, you can and should use `some` rather than `filter(...).length`. There's no reason to build a new array, and `some` has the advantage of stopping as soon as it knows the result, **and** you can use `&&` with your output because if the result is `false`, that will return `false` and not render anything:

```
return (
    documents.some((a) => a.types.length && a.value === toCheck)
        && <div>render this component</div>
);
```

Comment: Or change `.filter(...).length && ...` to `.some(...) && ...`? booleans don't render anything in React.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - I knew you could do that with `{something}`, but I didn't know it worked as the return value of a render function. Thanks!!

Comment: Re: return value of a render function; returning a boolean directly will cause type errors in TypeScript since [`FunctionComponent`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/bb9f40328b8349b856937b03b2f4d5c5fec789d1/types/react/v16/index.d.ts#L542-L548) returns a [`ReactElement`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/bb9f40328b8349b856937b03b2f4d5c5fec789d1/types/react/v16/index.d.ts#L142-L146) or `null`. But it does work at runtime. So to satisfy the type safety without affecting the behavior, you can just wrap the expression with `<>{...}</>`.

Answer (score 1):

A value of `0` is rendered as text, but some values are not rendered at all, like `null`, `undefined`, or `false`.  So a pattern that I've seen in some places is to coerce the type to boolean with `!!` if you're using it with `&&` in this way.  So here, it would be:

```
return (
    !!documents.filter((a) => a.types.length && a.value === toCheck).length && (
      <div>render this component</div>
    )
```

Comment: FWIW, although you can do `{undefiend}`, you can't return `undefined` from a render function -- React thinks it didn't return anything at all and complains (https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-sinoussi-vvkch?file=/src/App.js). So to not render, you need to return `null` or `false`.